# Computing square-root with bit shifting algorithm always outputs the same number

Tags: c++, algorithm, square-root

I'm struggling with the bit shifting algorithm for computing the square root of big numbers. I've got arrays of 32bit words and doesn't matter the input, the output is always the same number. Previously the algorithm worked with 1 bit per array cell, but when I switched to words in cells it doesn't work anymore.
I wrote methods that work perfectly separately (adding words, subtracting words, shifting bits to the right) but the whole program doesn't give what I expect.
When the input number has 0 in it's first position, the output is 0, when it has any number but the 1st cell of the array isn't 0, the output is always the same.

The variables:

```
uint32_t var[4] = {0,0,0,0};
uint32_t w_number[word_len] = {1, 0,0,234324};
uint32_t one[word_len]      = {0,0,0,0};
uint32_t var[word_len]      = {0,0,0,0};
uint32_t buff[word_len]     = {0,0,0,0};
uint32_t result[word_len]   = {0,0,0,0};
```

The code:

one[0] = 1L << 30;

```
while (isBigger(one, input))
{
    shiftR_word(one);
    shiftR_word(one);
}

while (!isZero(one))
{
    add_word(result, one, var); //the result of one+result is put in Var. 

    if ((isBigger(input, var) || equals(input, var))) // if (input >= var) 
    {       
        subtract_word(input, var, input); // input-=var
        shiftR_word(result);
        add_word(result, one, result);          
    }
    else
    {
        shiftR_word(result);            
    }
    shiftR_word(one);
    shiftR_word(one);
}

std::cout << "\nOut: ";
printAsBit(result);
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Here's the shifting algorithm I'm using that may cause the problems.

```
    void shiftR_word(uint32_t w_number[], int n=4)
    {
      // n - how many words
      //(n*32b word) >> 1
      bool* odd = new bool[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
          if( w_number[i] & 1 )
            odd[i]=true;
          else
            odd[i]=false;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          w_number[i] >>= 1;

        for (int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++)
        {
          if(odd[i])
          {
            w_number[i+1] = w_number[i+1] | 1 << 31;
          }
        }

      delete[] odd;
    }
```

The add function:

```
void add_word(uint32_t a[], uint32_t b[], uint32_t result[], int len=4)
{
  int carry=0;

  for (int i = len-1; i >=0; i--)
  {
    result[i]=a[i]+b[i]+carry;
    carry = (a[i]>result[i] || b[i]>result[i]) ? 1 : 0;

  } 
}
```

isBigger method:

```
bool isBigger(uint32_t a[],uint32_t b[] ,int len=4)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (a[i]>b[i])
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am unable to spot the error in the code, especially that all of the methods seem to work when I test them separately.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  There's not enough code and variable declarations here to know what's going on.  _all of the methods work_ No, they don't.  `add_word` doesn't calculate the carry correctly (`2 ^ 32` is 34, and the method you're using won't work because of overflow).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yes, I accidentally copied the wrong version of the `add_word` method. Now I edited and posted the one I'm using.

Comment: You can use binary search for calculating square root. It will take `O(log(n))`.

Comment: @AtulKumar I've read about all the algorithms and choosen this one, because I will have to write it in assembly once it works in c++ and this one seems to be the easiest to implement in assembly.

Answer (score 0):

`isBigger` does not work.  If you have (length 2) values of {2, 5} for `a` and {6, 3} for `b` it will return `true` when it should return false.  Inside the loop, you want to return false if `a[i] < b[i]`, and only check the next value if the two values are equal.

```
bool isBigger(const uint32_t a[], const uint32_t b[], int len = 4)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (a[i] > b[i])
        return true;
      if (a[i] < b[i])
          return false;
    }
    // Only get here if `a` and `b` are equal
    return false;
}
```

Additionally, `shiftR_word` has Undefined Behavior, because `w_number[i+1]` can be past the end of the array (when `i == n-1`, you'll access `w_number[n - 1 + 1]` or `w_number[n]`).  Your loop condition in this instance should be `i < n-1`.  However, that function is rather inefficient.  It can be rewritten to only need one loop and no memory allocation, but that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I've changed those 2 things, now the output is always like this '0000...10101010100'. It works for small numbers that have a perfect root (for example 16) but doesn't seem to work for bigger numbers. For 100 the output is 20, and it's the same for 1000 and more...
I was looking for diffrent methods of shifting words but didn't find anything better than that.

Comment: Well, nevermind, the output is still wrong, I get 7 for 16, the output is always a ` 0....1111 `.